# Why is ZFS stored in a tree structure?

Tags: filesystems, zfs

Apparently, in the ZFS (filesystem), there is an uberblock that points to the root of a zpool tree. Does anyone know why this tree makes things more efficient/reliable, and where the tree itself is stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the tree is to improve data integrity, partly by storing checksums [away](http://137.254.16.27/bonwick/entry/zfs_end_to_end_data) from the data blocks those checksums protect. The entire file system hierarchy forms a self-healing hash tree, or merkle tree. Here's a simplified description [I made earlier](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/14/building-a-nas-server-2/):

> [image: ZFS data integrity example]
>
> Going from left to right, directory 1 contains a pointer to file A, file A's checksum, and some other meta-data. But dir 1 is just another data block, which is pointed to by the uberblock. The uberblock therefore contains a checksum of dir 1, and so on. This does mean that every write to a file involves recalculating several checksums, all the way back to the root node (the uberblock). But ZFS's copy-on-write policy and transactional nature mitigate the performance penalty. Furthermore, ZFS is designed to take advantage of Moore's law: CPU cycles are cheap, but hard drives are slow.

ZFS also uses [ditto blocks](http://blogs.oracle.com/bill/entry/ditto_blocks_the_amazing_tape) to replicate the more important parts of the tree (i.e., the parts closer to the root), to further protect against corruption.

Comment: Just curious, but what is a "checksum", and what is "data integrity" supposed to mean?

Comment: What other benefits does this configuration allow zfs to provide, compared to other filesystems?

Comment: Take "data integrity" at face value - making sure things don't get changed or corrupted, basically.  As for a checksum, that's basically a hash taken of a file to verify it matches what you expect (no transcription errors or damage or anything).  This is a pretty important concept, so get familiar with it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum

Comment: To add to @Shinrai's comment, ZFS actually allows you use either a Fletcher checksum (computationally cheap) or a SHA-2 hash (more secure, i.e., less chance of false match, but more CPU intensive).

Comment: I have to admit, I'm the bad kind of computer geek who couldn't care less about *NIX anything, let alone Solaris! (I'm a hardware guy mostly, I guess), so I'm not that familiar with ZFS...but it's a pretty neat implementation now that I get to looking.